# How to sort by view count using Stack Exchange API in python?

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

So, I made a query using Stack Exchange Data Explorer:

```
SELECT TOP 100 Id 
AS [Post Link], 
ViewCount,
AnswerCount,
FavoriteCount,
CommentCount,
Score,
Tags

FROM Posts
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC
```

It returns just what I need, but I need to retrieve this by a python script.

Using the StackAPI, I can retrieve the questions, but I can't sort it by `view_count`.

I was trying to retrieve to the API like that:

```
from stackapi import StackAPI

SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
SITE.max_pages=1
top_viewed_questions = SITE.fetch('questions', sort='view_count', order='desc')

print(top_viewed_questions)
```

But it looks like `view_count` can't be sorted. Am I sorting wrong the `view_count` or there's no way I can do that?

Comment: You can't sort on `view_count`, you can check this URL: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions , scoll to the bottom there you will find all the sort options that you can use.

Comment: Oh. I see it now. Thanks for showing where I can see what I can use to sort!

Comment: The first SQL query comes from https://data.stackexchange.com which is updated every Sunday. The API is real-time and fairly better.

Comment: Good to know, I thought that the data in data.stackexchange.com was updated everyday. So it really looks like I should use the API then. Thanks.

Comment: How about fetching the questions you want, store them in an array and sort them?

Comment: The problem is I only wanted the top 100 most viewed posts. To be able to fetch the questions and sort them by view count correctly, I think I would have to retrieve all questions from the site, sort them by view count and select the first 100 which is impossible.

Comment: How about fetching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits, then find questions in the API and sort by view count? These *must* be the questions with the highest view count. Oh, and why don't you use SQL Data Explorer? While it's updated weekly, the first 100 questions will not change for a period of time.

Comment: Yeah. It is a fact that the first 100 questions won't change, but my teacher asked us to fetch the questions by code, so I couldn't use the SQL Data Explorer. 

I will look into fetching stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits as you said, it looks like a nice way out to my problem, as I think it will really retrieve the most viewed questions.

Thanks again bro! :)

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/MNi5Gh3W) is a piece of code that will help you get all the questions' ids, stored in the `ids` array. Pass those to the API (semicolon-separated, max 100 at once) and get the *exact* view count. If you need help, ping me ;)